# How can I use Hours, Minutes and Seconds in a MSSQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I tried many ways but can't find it. I'm building a query and wanted to get the data between hours, minutes and seconds.

Already tried ways like:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLENAME TB
WHERE (TB.DATE BETWEEN '25/11/2013 00:00:00' AND '25/11/2013 23:59:59')
```

Comment: Well TABLE is a reserved word, so you would only be able to use a Table named Table by using [TABLE]. Please don't use reserved names for table or column names. Oh and can you add some table structures, sample data and tell us what the actual problem is!

Comment: What does `get the data between hours, minutes and seconds.` mean? As Steve suggests, add some sample data and desired results (preferably with a [db<>fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle)). Also `BETWEEN` is very dangerous for date range queries, always use >= start of range and < day _after_ end of range. Similarly regional, ambiguous formats like `d/m/y` are dangerous - always use safe, unambiguous formats, like `yyyymmdd`. These and lots more explained at [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates).

Comment: Oh, I just used the keyword table for the example. When I tried to build the query only with 'dd/mm/yyyy' I can't get the records because it has also hours, minutes and seconds in the field.

Comment: OK let's see actual table schema, sample data and expected results. Is the column data type `datetime` or `varchar`?

Answer (score -2):

You can use something like this

```
select * from TB
WHERE cast(date_time_attribute as time ) between '10:00:00' and '23:00:00'
```

To also impose a constraint on the date, you can simply add this ->

```
select * from TB
WHERE ( cast(date_time_attribute as time ) between '10:00:00' and '23:00:00' )
AND date(date_time_attribute) = 'dd:mm:yyyy'
```

date_time_attribute is the attribute containing the datetime

Comment: `date()` is not a function and `dd:mm:yyyy` is a really janky format to suggest.

Comment: @AaronBertrand My bad, for sql-server, we have DATEPART() 
This can be used instead of date()

Comment: Actually 'dd/mm/yyyy' is the data format in my country, so in my company we use it as a pattern for all date fields.

Comment: @artu0s `date` columns don't have a format, they are stored in binary. If you are storing them as `varchar` then you have a problem anyway

Comment: @artu0s That'll have to change if you ever hire an American, or someone who uses American regional / dateformat / language settings, or log on to an RDP server or jump box where this is the default, and can lead to confusion when you interact with Americans outside of work (like on this site). Meanwhile if you use a standard, unambiguous format, it'll never break. Please read all the links offered in the "Regional formats" section [here](https://sqlblog.org/dates).

Comment: Sadly we are running a legacy system for like 20 years, it will be really hard to make these changes right now, we now have more than 300 tables. I actually followed @AaronBertrand tips and used my date plus one day so I can get my expected data from database.